# Sets and hashmaps don't have constant lookup time?

Tags: algorithm, performance, hash, time-complexity, trie

I was reading about tries and this topcoder article (https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/using-tries/) says:

The tries can insert and find strings in O(L) time (where L represent the length of a single word). This is much faster than set , but is it a bit faster than a hash table.

I had always learned that sets and hash tables were really fast for looking things up and that they had constant lookup time. Is this not true? Why is it "much faster" than a set? And it also seems to imply that hash tables have different lookup time than sets too. I always thought that sets and hash tables were implemented in pretty much the same way except that one stores some object.

Answer (score 3):

The referenced article is not comparing a trie with an abstract "set" datastructure; it is comparing the trie with the C++ standard library `std::set`, which is a search tree, usually a red-black tree, which allows you to iterate the contents in sorted order. (C++ also has `std::unordered_set`, which is based on a hash table, but the article may have been written before that was part of the standard library.)

Hash tables are (on average) O(1) only if the hash can be computed in O(1), since the hash of the key must be computed before any lookup is done. For string keys, most hash functions need to look at every character in the key, so they are O(L) in the length of the string. (This rather obvious fact is for some reason often skipped over in discussion of hashtable computational complexity.) Since both the trie and the hashtable must eventually verify that the provided key is equal to the candidate key in the container, there is an O(L) factor in both cases.

However, tries still have advantages. For example, they can be iterated in lexicographic order, like `std::set`, but usually faster, whereas hashtables can only be iterated in some non-deterministic order. So if you need to do prefix searches, the hashtable is not an appropriate datastructure.

Comment: Good answer. Another thing worth noting is that a trie might be very fast for small sets that fit in cache. But for larger ones, a lookup is likely to touch many more cache lines than a hash table, which could easily slow it down by an order of magnitude.